# Animations and CPU - best practice?

Tags: android, performance, animation

I am developing a game with a few `Animation`s running in infinite loops (live background - think of the home screen of Angry Birds). However, very quickly the app consumes 90% or more of my CPU (Nexus One / Froyo). These are very simple translation animations applied to `ImageView`s. Game development is novel to me, and I was wondering if there were best practices to avoid such CPU overload. Is the `Animation` object known to be expensive? Would direct bitmap drawing on the canvas be better suited?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: draw less frames? Insert sleep/relinquish in draw loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OpenGL directly.  Using Animation is sitting you on top of a full view system doing a lot more than you need for doing a game-like experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am looking into AndEngine for the purpose.